# Как обернуть выделенный текст в теги, используя Brackets?

Tags: adobe-brackets

Как обернуть выделенный текст в теги, используя Brackets?
Также мешает автозакрытие тега, при редактировании html. Приходиться постоянно удалять появившийся раньше времени закрывающий тег. Есть решение?

Answer (score 1):

Автозакрытие тегов можно убрать так.
Выбрать пункт меню `Отладка -> Открыть файл настроек`.
Откроется два файла `defaultPreferences.json` (файл глобальных настроек) и `brackets.json` (файл ваших личных настроек).
Добавляете строку

```
"closeTags": false
```

в файл `brackets.json` в место между скобками { }. Если вы добавите эту строку последней, то запятую после строки ставить не нужно.
Насчет первого вопроса :"Как обернуть выделенный текст в теги, используя Brackets?" , не могли бы вы уточнить что имеется в виду под тегами. Какими ?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то при установленном плагине Emmet, выделите нужный кусок кода нажмите Shift+Ctrl+A , появится всплывающая строка напишите нужный тег и нажмите Enter, выделенный текст будет обернут в нужный тег.